# Golang reference list from within custom struct

Tags: struct, go, composition

I have the following block of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "container/list"
)

type Foo struct {
    foo list  //want a reference to the list implementation   
             //supplied by the language
}


func main() {
   //empty
```

}

When compiling I receive the following message:

> use of package list not in selector

My question is, how do I reference `list` within a `struct`?  Or is this not the proper idiom in Go for wrapping structures.  (Composition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two problems:

1. importing the `fmt` package without using it. In Go unused imports result in compile-time errors;
2. `foo` is not declared correctly: `list` is a package name not a type; you want to use a type from the `container/list` package.

Corrected code:

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
)

type Foo struct {
    // list.List represents a doubly linked list.
    // The zero value for list.List is an empty list ready to use.
    foo list.List
}

func main() {}
```

You can execute the above code in the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2va5eA4ByX).
You should also consider reading [the official documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/) of the `container/list` package.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might also want to know that Go allows you to embed types within a struct or interface. Read more in the [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) guide and decide wether or not this makes sense for your particular case.